# Check the surrounding neighbors of a matrix element in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have a 480-by-640 matrix `A`. For each pixel, I want to check its neighbors. The neighbors of the pixel are determined by a value `N`. For example, this is a part of matrix `A` where all the zeros are the neighbours of pixel `X` when `N=3`:

```
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   X   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

As shown, because `N=3`, all these zeros are pixel `X`'s neighbors. The problem is if `X` is located before the index `N=3`. Here the neighbors will be pixels with one values:

```
    X   1   1   1   0   0   0
    1   1   1   1   0   0   0
    1   1   1   1   0   0   0
    1   1   1   1   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
    0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Could anyone advise on how to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to proceed is just to pad your array with with values that do not return true for whatever you are checking (say, if you're looking for nonzeros, pad with zeros, or if you're looking for finite values, pad with `NaN`.) The `padarray` function can do this for you, but requires the Image Processing Toolbox*. Otherwise, you can pad arrays yourself. For example, an unoptimized way to proceed might be

```
A = rand(m,n);
Apadded = [zeros(N,2*N+n); [zeros(m,N), A, zeros(m,N)]; zeros(N,2*N+n)];
for i = N+1:N+m+1
    for j = N+1:N+n+1
        % Process neighborhood of A(i,j)  
    end
end
```

*Also note that these sorts of "sliding neighborhood" operations, being common in image processing, are [implemented for you in the Image Processing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/performing-sliding-neighborhood-operations.html).